# Jpanel disappears after changing layout from null to BoxLayou

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a program in java, similar to Quizlet.

I created a class for each Jpanel which has the layout set to null. The only class that doesn't have the null layout is the one that manages and contains all the JPanels, which has the CardLayout.

Anyways, everything was working fine, the problem occurred in one of my classes that contains a Jpanel that loads each quiz. I called it LoadMenu.

The GUI was working just fine, and I just wanted to check out the box layout, so I switched it from null layout to box. Then I realized all of my components, except for one, disappeared on that layout. Now when I changed the layout back to null, everything is still gone, and the JPanel all together completely disappeared. I hit `Control-Z` and undo any changes, but it's still gone.

Is there anyway I can restore it to what it looked like before?

Thank you

Not sure if this helps but this is the loadMenu class

```
public class LoadMenu extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private QuizManager manager;
    private FileManager file = new FileManager();
    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private JButton nextButton;
    private JButton refreshButton;
    private JButton backButton;
    private ProblemSet problemSetList;

    LoadMenu(ProblemSet newProblemSetList, QuizManager newManager){
        manager = newManager;
        problemSetList = newProblemSetList;

        JPanel loadMenu = new JPanel();
        loadMenu.setLayout(null);
        loadMenu.setBounds(1, 0, 681, 426);
        add(loadMenu);
        loadMenu.setLayout(null);
        loadMenu.setBounds(1, 0, 681, 426);

        JLabel selectQuizLabel = new JLabel("Select Quiz");
        selectQuizLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        selectQuizLabel.setBounds(261, 104, 110, 31);
        loadMenu.add(selectQuizLabel);

        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setBounds(274, 194, 153, 22);
        loadMenu.add(comboBox);

        nextButton = new JButton("Next");

        nextButton.setBounds(530, 370, 139, 43);import junit.framework.TestCase;
        import junit.framework.TestCase;

        loadMenu.add(nextButton);
        nextButton.addActionListener(this);
        listQuizNames();

        refreshButton = new JButton("Refresh");
        refreshButton.addActionListener(this);
        refreshButton.setBounds(241, 229, 139, 31);
        loadMenu.add(refreshButton);

        backButton = new JButton("Back");
        backButton.addActionListener(this);
        backButton.setBounds(12, 370, 139, 43);
        loadMenu.add(backButton);


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if(src == nextButton){
            manager.startQuiz((String)comboBox.getSelectedItem());

        }
        else if(src == refreshButton){
            listQuizNames();

        }
        else{
            manager.showNextCard("startMenu");
        }
    }

    public void listQuizNames(){
        ArrayList<String> quizList = new ArrayList<String>();
        file.readQuizNames(quizList);
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(quizList.toArray()));

    }
}
```

Comment: However if your panels are in a jframe, try asigning a size to your jpanel or adjust the size of your jpanel

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the panel to a JFrame, it might help

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(loadmenu);
```

In the main function or the constructor - suit yourself

```
setVisible(true);
```

Hope it works!!